# Tabla descuadrada - se distorsiona - Angular

Tags: css, angular, sass

tengo un problema con Angular, en el detalle del front, donde tengo una tabla y los siguientes campos, el detalle es que las celdas se me distorsionan y no se que pueda hacer, he visto la documentación de Primeface de angular en tabla y ya intente pero la información de mis registros se me desfasa por completo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el siguiente:

```html
<p-table #dt [value]="institucions" [columns]="cols" responsiveLayout="scroll"
             [rows]="10" [globalFilterFields]="['institucion','representante']" 
             [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,20,30]" 
             [showCurrentPageReport]="true" currentPageReportTemplate="Mostrando {first} de {last} de {totalRecords} registros" 
             [(selection)]="selectedInstitucions" selectionMode="multiple" [rowHover]="true" 
             dataKey="id" [scrollable]="true"  scrollHeight="580px" scrollDirection="both" styleClass="p-datatable-sm, p-datatable-gridlines">
                <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
                    <div class="flex flex-column md:flex-row md:justify-content-between md:align-items-center">
                        <h5 class="m-0 highlighted">Lista de instituciones</h5>
                        <span class="block mt-2 md:mt-0 p-input-icon-left">
                            <i class="pi pi-search"></i>
                            <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" placeholder="Buscar..." />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 3em;">
                            <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
                        </th>
                        <th style="flex: 1;" pSortableColumn="id">No.<p-sortIcon field="id"></p-sortIcon></th>
                        <th style="flex: 1;" pSortableColumn="rfc">RFC<p-sortIcon field="rfc"></p-sortIcon></th>
                        <th style="flex: 1;" pSortableColumn="institucion">Institución<p-sortIcon field="institucion"></p-sortIcon></th>
                        <th style="flex: 1;" pSortableColumn="representante">Representante<p-sortIcon field="representante"></p-sortIcon></th>
                        <th style="flex: 1;" pSortableColumn="area">Área<p-sortIcon field="area"></p-sortIcon></th>
                        <th style="flex: 1;" pSortableColumn="sector">Sector<p-sortIcon field="sector"></p-sortIcon></th>
                        <th style="flex: 1;" pSortableColumn="estatus">Estatus<p-sortIcon field="estatus"></p-sortIcon></th>
                        <th style="flex: 1;" pSortableColumn="telefono">Teléfono<p-sortIcon field="telefono"></p-sortIcon></th>
                        <th style="flex: 1;" pSortableColumn="correo">Correo<p-sortIcon field="correo"></p-sortIcon></th>
                        <th style="flex: 1;">Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-institucion>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 3em;">
                            <p-tableCheckbox [value]="institucion"></p-tableCheckbox>
                        </td>
                        <td style="flex: 1;">
                            {{institucion.No}}
                        </td>
                        <td style="flex: 1;">
                            {{institucion.rfc}}
                        </td>
                        <td style="flex: 1;">
                            {{institucion.institucion}}
                        </td>
                        <td style="flex: 1;">
                            {{institucion.representante}}
                        </td>
                        <td style="flex: 1;">
                            {{institucion.area}}
                        </td>
                        <td style="flex: 1;">
                            {{institucion.sector}}
                        </td>
                        <td style="flex: 1;">
                            {{institucion.estatus}}
                        </td>
                        <td style="flex: 1;">
                            {{institucion.telefono}}
                        </td>
                        <td style="flex: 1;">
                            {{institucion.correo}}
                        </td>
                        <td style="flex: 1;">
                            <div class="flex">
                                <button pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-pencil" class="p-button-rounded p-button-success mr-2" (click)="openNewFormEmpre(institucion,true)" pTooltip="Editar"></button>
                                <button pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-trash" class="p-button-rounded p-button-warning" (click)="deleteProduct(institucion)" pTooltip="Eliminar" tooltipPosition="left"></button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
            </p-table>
```

He intentado varias cosas con estilos pero no me hace la diferencia, si me pudieran ayudar con este aspecto se los agradecería muchisimo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolvi dejando los siguientes parametros de p-table:"

```html
responsiveLayout="scroll"
[rowHover]="true" 
[scrollable]="false"  
scrollHeight="500px" 
scrollDirection="both"
```